# hovering on first child will take effect on last child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i have some child based hovering effect on my project.

### My codes are

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <a href="">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
       </a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

### so my css are

```
    a i:first-child{
       position: absolute;
       top:0px;
    }

    a i:last-child{
       position: absolute;
       top:30px;
       visibility:hidden;
    }
```

when hovering on first child i want to take it `top:-30px` and `visibility:hidden` and last child to vice-versa

### I have tried

```
ul.socials.jump a i:first-child:hover ul.socials.jump a i:last-child{
   position: absolute;
   visibility: visible;
   top: 0%;
   transition:all .4s ease;
}
```

but not working :(

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: Are you missing a comma in your CSS (after the first `:hover`)?

Comment: It's not apparent what you actually want to accomplish. Moving the first one up when you hover over it immediately undoes your hovering over it. Are you just trying to show the second one on hover?

Comment: `ul.socials.jump a i:first-child:hover ul.socials.jump a i:last-child` <- this code is wrong. It looks like you want it to detect the hover on first child and apply the style to last child but you can't 'reverse' CSS selectors. You can use `ul.socials.jump a i:first-child:hover + i` to apply the style to the 2nd `i`, but not the way you do it. [See my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9w5coh8/1/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify both elements on hover, you will need two separate `:hover` rules.

One for the first child:

```
ul.socials.jump a i:first-child:hover {
   visibility: hidden;
   top: -30px;
}
```

And one for the last child, but to target the last child on first child hover, you don't need to repeat the first portion of your selector — just use a sibling combinator:

```
ul.socials.jump a i:first-child:hover + i:last-child {
   visibility: visible;
   top: 0%;
}
```

You don't need to redeclare `position: absolute`, and your transition ought to be declared on `a i:first-child, a i:last-child` and not on the hover state *unless* you expect the transition to only apply when the elements *leave* hover.

Comment: But when you use `i:first-child:hover + i:last-child`, it would only work if there are 2 elements in the same level. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hca0oas/).

Comment: @Billy: Indeed, although given the OP's use of `i:last-child` in the original CSS, I think it's safe to assume there will only ever be 2 elements in the same level at a time. If such an assumption cannot be made, the OP should specify this, and the selector modified according to their real needs.

Comment: Yup, or I think it's safer to omit `:last-child` since that would work all the time, even if he accidentally added another element. The sibling selector can only select its immediate sibling, so with `:last-child`, it makes no difference and would break if there are more siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the hover is better served on the anchor tag.

```
a:hover i:first-child {
   position:relative;
   top:-30px;
}

a:hover i:last-child {
   visibility:visible;
}
```

It's much more legible, and the hover is more likely to stay active even with the shifting position of the children.

It would also help if you added a class to the link and set its display to `inline-block`, such as

```
a.hoverchild { display:inline-block }
```

That causes the 'blank' space inside the link to be hoverable as well, so that when the children move, the cursor (being inside the link's block, still) is still keeping the `:hover` active.

If you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do, you might actually be better off using `float:left` like this:

```
a.hoverchild {
    display:inline-block;
}

a.hoverchild:hover i {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daiopowen/3ghxw017/2/) to demonstrate.

Comment: This is an excellent point which I hadn't considered. 30px sounds like a pretty huge shift in position. Perhaps the OP should clarify what exactly it is they're trying to accomplish, rather than simply describing it in terms of what they have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think you can use sibling option in css using "~" sign to solve this problem.

Check out following [`JSfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/sarbasish/3ghxw017/3/) to see your requirement